# browser `console.error` stack trace from error, not where console.error was called?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using `console.error` in Chrome dev tools to show errors. It seems that the stack trace it shows is the point where `console.error` is called, rather than the `error.stack` property of the error I pass to it. Understandable, because it doesn't know that the object is an error with a stack property.
But I'd like to make it work if I can; is there any way to get `console.error` to print a stack trace (in the nice collapsed-but-expandable form that it uses) that I pass to it, rather than the point of call?

Example:

```
function err() {
  throw new Error('hi there')
}
function f() {
  try {
    err()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

That prints the stack at `f()`, not `err()`. Is there perhaps a variant form of `console.error` that allows passing in the stack?

To be clear, there are two stacks printed: the first, in red, is part of `error.stack`. The second, which appears when you click the left disclosure triangle, comes from `console.error()` (or `console.trace()`, they're the same). Here's what I mean:

[image]

The indented lines are part of the message (`err.toString()`). The last two lines are seen when you click the disclosure triangle at the top left next to "Error:". That last stack is what I'd like to fix. As you can see it's at the wrong line, and omits the "err" function entirely, because it's just the stack at the point of call to `console.error()`.

Comment: Just use console.trace()

Comment: https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api#customizing-stack-traces

Comment: or you can use: console. error(e.stack);

Comment: @vlad-grigoryan: console.trace() has the same behavior as console.error. And `console.error(e.stack)` is the same. The proper stack trace is shown in red as part of the message (as part of err.toString() or err.stack I believe), but when you click the disclosure triangle, the stack shown there is still the stack to the `console.error` call (or console.trace).

Comment: @GaryO this is what print to my console with your code :                                                        `VM63:8 Error: hi there
    at err (<anonymous>:2:9)
    at f (<anonymous>:6:5)
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: @wOxxOm: that looks cool, but also looks like a lot of work. Also I still don't see how you'd get that structured stack trace out to Chrome dev tools.

Comment: @vlad-grigoryan: I don't think I can paste an image into a comment, but I think you're seeing the `error.stack` property. Click the disclosure triangle on the left side of the error to see the actual clickable stack -- that's the one I'm talking about. You'll see that `err` is missing there, and the line number there is the line of the `console.error` call.

Comment: The article says "If you assign a different function value to Error.prepareStackTrace that function is used to format stack traces." Sounds straightforward to me.

Comment: I think that will only affect what's printed by `err.stack`. I'll see if I can add a screenshot to my question to clarify.

Comment: @GaryO I see. nice question.

Comment: I don't think you can. A console message always records the line from which `console.log` was called, and you cannot change that.

Comment: Thanks. I think my best option is to just use `console.log()` and style the result red. That avoids the incorrect stack trace disclosure triangle altogether.